# How to decrease size of a large postgresql table

Tags: postgresql, indexing, diskspace

I have a postgresql table that is "frozen" i.e. no new data is coming into it. The table is strictly used for reading purposes. The table contains about 17M records. The table has 130 columns and can be queried multiple different ways. To make the queries faster, I created indices for all combinations for filters that can be used. So I have a total of about 265 indexes on the table. Each index is about 1.1 GB. This makes the total table size to be around 265 GB. I have vacuumed the table as well.

**Question**

- Is there a way to further bring down the disk usage of this table?
- Is there a better way to handle queries for "frozen" tables that never get any data entered into them?

Comment: Try creating one index per column rather than one index for each combination. Postgres can combine multiple indexes in a single query.

Comment: I've found examples of queries where single column indexes didn't help. In some cases the single column indices weren't being picked up thats why I created multicolumn indices. But I will try it out again with a concrete example.

Comment: "I've found examples of queries where single column indexes didn't help"  That can certainly happen in specific cases, but 256 times on one table is not so likely.

Comment: `The table has 130 columns` That looks more like a spreadsheet. Maybe it is time to normalise?

Answer (score 0):

If your table or indexes are bloated, then `VACUUM FULL tablename` could shrink them.  But if they aren't bloated then this won't do any good.  This is not a benign operation, it will lock the table for a period of time (needing rebuild hundreds of index, probably a long period of time) and generate large amounts of IO and of WAL, the last of which will be especially troublesome for replicas.  So I would test it on a non-production clone to see it actually shrinks things and see about how long of a maintenance window you will need to declare.

Other than that, be more judicious in your choice of indexes.  How did you get the list of "all combinations for filters that can be used"?  Was it by inspecting your source code, or just by tackling slow queries one by one until you ran out of slow queries?  Maybe you can look at snapshots of `pg_stat_user_indexes` taken a few days apart to see if all them are actually being used.

Are these mostly two-column indexes?